# How to keep the vehicle stopped on the road for 1000 seconds?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

In my model, I need a vehicle to stop on the road for 1000 seconds. But after about 240 seconds the vehicle disappears from the road.

In the omnetpp.ini file I set the following parameters:

```
*.node[0].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 1
*.node[0].veinsmobility.accidentStart = 73s
*.node[0].veinsmobility.accidentDuration = 1000s
```

In the following link `https://sourceforge.net/p/sumo/mailman/message/35596802/` has a similar question. But I did not understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you say in which way your scenario is similar? Do you see a warning about the vehicle skipping the stop or being teleported?

Comment: The vehicle simply disappears into the lane.

Comment: Try searching in the SUMO log file (or log window) for a warning message regarding teleportation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip, @ChristophSommer. I looked in the SUMO log, and there really was a teleport warning.

Searching, I found the `<time-to-teleport value="-1"/>` tag, which should be inserted into the configuration section of the * .sumo.cfg file, to disable teleport.